# PHP & LDAP - retrieving user attributes from sAMAccountName

Tags: php, ldap

Is it possible to bind to the ldap server with a users credentials and return that users OU membership details?

I'm creating a system where the user logins in, binds with the LDAP server, and depending on what OU they are a member of the proper view is rendered.

Currently I can return some details about the user, but it requires I use the users CN. I would prefer the user to not have to type in their name.

```
$user='xxx';
$pass='yyy';
    $ldaprdn  = $user.'@x.xxx.com';     // ldap rdn or dn :: We concatenate the username with the domain to create the proper string for querying the ldap server
    $ldappass = $pass;  // associated password

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("x.xxx.com")
            or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

        if ($ldapconn) {
            // binding to ldap server
            $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
        }

            // verify binding
            if ($ldapbind) {
            $ds = 'nx.xxx.com';
            $dn ="cn=Jonathan Rxxxr,OU=MIS Department,OU=People,DC=x,DC=xxx,dc=com";
            $filter="(objectClass=user)";

            $justthese = array("ou", "sn", "dn", "givenname", "mail");

             $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $justthese);

            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
            $ou = strtolower($info[0]["mail"][0]);
            echo $ou;
            print_r($info);//I print the array just for debugging purposes

                echo $info["count"]." entries returned\n";
                echo "success";
```

Comment: I can't fully unterstand the question. You say you do not want the user to type her name but on the other hand the user shall be authenticated to the server. How can that be done without providing a name?

Comment: Maybe you could use modauthsspi to get the username if they're already logged in via windows if you're using apache